# Where do you all host your CratCMS sites?

Tags: server

I'm very curious to know what are the most popular hosting services chosen by CratCMS developers. Perhaps I'm missing out in some gems!

Please let me know what you love about your favorite hosting service and at least one thing you dislike about it.

Comment: Hey Brian, we're going to close this thread as off-topic, since it's about hosting, and not about Craft itself. (There's also an argument to be made about it being a subjective question, but that's a different story.) However, **it is a valuable question**, but much better suited for [a forum like Google+](https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/106505340287442511226) rather than Stack Exchange. Feel free to post it on G+ instead!

Answer (score 1):

Anything that you can config and auto-deploy through using https://forge.laravel.com/ (Digital Ocean, Rackspace, Amazon).